# Angularjs login twitter and linkedin custom without oath0 third party service

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter, linkedin-api

i have developed application in angular and i am done with facebook login custom without using Oath0 third party service.
i am done with login twitter with  Oath service but not found any solution without Oath0 third party service.
So, is there any idea for the linkedin and twitter login in angular without using Oath0 third party service?

Comment: can you tell me what are steps for twitter login ?i tried with oauth but it's not working.i am nt getting where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example of twitter and linkedin login. In your app module configuration make sure you have added ngsanitize

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute', 'ngMessages','ngCookies','ngSanitize']);
```

in your controller file

in login controller

```
app.controller("loginsController", function ($location, $scope, $http, $rootScope, constant,$q,twitterService) {
twitterService.initialize();
$scope.LinkedfoundMe = function (me) {
    $scope.me = me;
    $scope.$digest();
    $scope.LoginSocialUsers($scope.me);
};
$scope.connectTWButton = function() {
    twitterService.connectTwitter().then(function() {
        if (twitterService.isReady()) {
            //if the authorization is successful, hide the connect button and display the tweets
               $scope.refreshTimeline();

            $scope.connectedTwitter = true;
        } else {
         }
    });
}
 $scope.refreshTimeline = function() {
    twitterService.getTweetUser().then(function(data) {
        if(data[0].user.id != null || data[0].user.id != undefined){
            var TwData = {};
           TwData.firstName =data[0].user.name; 
           TwData.lastName =""; 
           TwData.emailAddress =""; 
           TwData.id =data[0].user.id; 
            $scope.LoginSocialUsers(TwData);
        }
    },function(){
        $scope.rateLimitError = true;
    });
}});
```

Now I have implemented linkedin login with jQuery and pass data to angular function. Below is code for linkedin login with js sdk.

Add javascript file to your html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
 api_key: YOUR_APP_KEY 
 onLoad: displayLinkedInLogin 
 authorize: false  
 </script>
```

IN your controller file

```
function linkedAuthLink() {
IN.User.authorize(function () {
});
}
function displayLinkedInLogin() {
IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);
}
function onLinkedInAuth() {
IN.API.Profile("me")
        .fields(["firstName", "lastName", "emailAddress",       "pictureUrl", "id", "headline", "location", "summary", "positions", "twitter-accounts"])
        .result(displayProfiles);
}
function displayProfiles(profiles, $scope) {
member = profiles.values[0];
angular.element($("#logincontroller")).scope().LinkedfoundMe(member);
}
```

for linkedin you have to call controller from your html using ng-controller this is the only way to make it work.
you need to download oauth.js file from below link [oauth.js file for twitter auth](https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-js)

Answer (score 0):

At least for Twitter I can tell you that you will most probably not be able to authenticate without OAuth.

Twitter username/password authentication is highly restricted for specific business cases and companies who are ready to pay for it. The only app that I know have access to this feature is instagram.

You can make a request for this feature but for working closely with the team, if you do not have a big company to support your request it has 99% chance to be denied.

To enhance my point, I'd like to say that I am the developer of a third party library for Twitter and when meeting with their staff regarding this specific subject they told me that I should not add username/password authentication to the library as the number of customers with such privileges are very restricted.